# ABP and .Net 5 problem retrieving records

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate, abp

I am working with ABP 6.5.0. I have an App Service that retrieves all the tenants running the GetAll method.

I have overwrite the CreateFilteredQuery and it runs the following code:

```
protected override IQueryable<Tenant> CreateFilteredQuery(PagedBusinessResultRequestDto input)
    {
        IQueryable<Tenant> result = null;

        result = Repository
                   .GetAll()
                       .Include(b => b.Branches)
                           .ThenInclude(bc => bc.BranchCategories)
                   .WhereIf(!input.Keywords.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(), x => x.Name.Contains(input.Keywords) || x.TenantDescription.Contains(input.Keywords))
                   .Where(x => x.Id != AppConsts.DefaultTenantId && x.IsActive && x.IsValid);

        return result;
    }
```

When I call the Rest API (Business.GetAll), the tenant records are retrieved, but these records don't include the **Branches** and **BrachCategories** when the user is logged into the application. However, when the user is not logged into the app, it works as expected.

Something interesting I found was debugging the code. If I review the `result` variable before the **CreateFilteredQuery** method finishes the execution, the **branch** and **branchCategories** records are retrieved correctly. However, if I don't review the `result` variable, **branch** and **branchCategories** records are not retrived.

Any idea what could be happening here?

Thanks in advances.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem doing this:

```
public override async Task<PagedResultDto<BusinessDto>> GetAllAsync(PagedBusinessResultRequestDto input)
        {
            using (_unitOfWorkManager.Current.DisableFilter(AbpDataFilters.MustHaveTenant))
            {
                return await base.GetAllAsync(input);
            }
        }
```

I had tried this other code and it didn't work, but for some reason it is incorrectly, I am thinking that Abp applies automatically a filter the `result` variable.

```
public override Task<PagedResultDto<BusinessDto>> GetAllAsync(PagedBusinessResultRequestDto input)
        {
            Task<PagedResultDto<BusinessDto>> result;
            using (_unitOfWorkManager.Current.DisableFilter(AbpDataFilters.MustHaveTenant))
            {
                result = base.GetAllAsync(input);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Thanks everyone for your time.